# jquery ui datepicker set tomorrows date as default

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, default

I think I'm missing something pretty straight forward here..

How do you set the default date on the jqueryui to tomorrow ?

Answer (score 3):

Initialize a datepicker with the defaultDate option specified.

```
    $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +1 });
```

Get or set the `defaultDate` option, after `init`.

```
    //getter
    var defaultDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );
    //setter
    $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +1 );
```

see: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Answer (score 0):

Or if your don't want back dates then you can use as this while initialzing the `datepicker`

```
minDate: +1
```